# TensorFlow: integrate output of neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, numerical-methods

I have a neural network that takes as input two parameters:

```
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
```

in my loss function I need to integrate the output over `t`, but I can't figure out a way of doing this, because the only numerical integration function available in TensorFlow, `tf.contrib.integrate.odeint_fixed`, cannot take a Tensor as function, since it can't be called:

### Call

```
t = tf.constant(np.linspace(0.0,1.0,100), dtype = tf.float64 )

integ = tf.contrib.integrate.odeint_fixed(model.output, 
                                          0.0, 
                                          t, 
                                          method = "rk4")
```

### Output

```
...

<ipython-input-5-c79e79b75391> in loss(model, t, x)
     24                                                 0.0,
     25                                                 t,
---> 26                                                 method = "rk4")

...

TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

Not to mention that I'm also clueless on how to treat `x` in this computation, it's supposed to be held fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tf.contrib.integrate.odeint_fixed` appears to be for integrating ordinary differential equations (ODEs). If I understand you correctly, however, you want to approximate the definite integral of your model's output, let's call it  `y`, sampled at `t`.

To do so, you could use the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), for which you find a possible implementation in [tensorflows AUC function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py#L816). In your case, it could look like:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops

def trapezoidal_integral_approx(t, y):
    return math_ops.reduce_sum(
            math_ops.multiply(t[:-1] - t[1:],
                              (y[:-1] + y[1:]) / 2.), 
            name='trapezoidal_integral_approx')
```

where `y` would be the output of your model.

Comment: nitpicking: dividing by 2 might be better to do outside `reduce_sum` in terms of runtime.